# read gurobi lp file and list constraints

Tags: solver, gurobi

Does Gurobi python library provide the ability to load the lp file and list the constraints?

Like Model.addConstrs(), can we load the lp file and get all the constraints?

Comment: What do you mean by 'list' ?

Comment: Something like model.getConstrs() and we can loop through them.